# Travel options to the UK, Rome and Norway

Tags: visas

A Filipino citizen was invited by a family to visit the UK. At the same time they want to visit Rome, Italy and if possible Norway. Is this possible? What visas do they need to apply for? And how long does it take usually for the decision? They are planning to visit the UK on July 13. Thanks.

Comment: They can apply up to 3 months in advance of their travel date, I would recommend they do that bearing in mind that Schengen and U.K. visa applications can’t be made simultaneously since they will need to provide their passports for each. They should obtain the U.K. visa first if that will be their prime destination. The VFS site for the Philippines states that the standard processing time for a U.K. visa is 15 days, there are priority services that can speed this up for an extra fee https://vfsglobal.co.uk/philippines/frequently_asked_questions.html

Answer (score 2):

They need one Schengen visa for Italy and Norway, or two separate ones. If they visit one directly after the other, they need one visa; if they return to the UK, they need either a double-entry visa or two separate ones.

You also need an UK visa, which is a completely separate process. However, it can be easier to get a visa for places like the UK or Schengen area if one has a visa in another Western industrialized country; if you return to the UK from Italy/Norway, it helps if you already have an UK visa.

I can't answer average processing times in the Philippines.

Comment: Will a visa for the UK be needed?

Comment: @phoog for completeness, Philippine citizens normally do require visas to visit the UK. I infer the asker knew that because they mentioned being 'invited' to visit the UK.